# Load view after data is loaded

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, masonry

I have some trouble. I am using this plugin "angular-masonry" (it's on Github) to dynamically build the grid on the page. When the page loads I get this:
http://joxi.ru/YBQPVP3JTJCwfIgLgbc

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container" style="width:80%">
      <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 40px">
        Category: {{category.text}}
      </h1>
      <div>(masonry='' load-images="false")
        <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="portal in category.claim_portals" style='width:50%;float:left'>
          <div>
            <h3>(style='margin-left:30px')
              Portal: {{portal.text}}
            </h3>
            <div class="category-list" ng-repeat="claim in portal.portal_claim" style="margin-bottom:2px">
              <div class="claim_sections">
                <claimforlist claim="claim"></claimforlist>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But after resizing browser window, everything becomes normal and looks like this:
http://joxi.ru/iBQPVP3JTJCUfLnoqQQ

I think that view loads earlier than JSON data arrives. 
Can anyone help and tell me how can I load view after the data has arrived? Or if you know another reason of such an issue, please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: you can add ng-if like <div class="container" style="width:80%" ng-if="category">

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and added but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a scope boolean variable with value set to `false`, and change the value to true on your http promise success.

Code sample:

```
function myController($scope, YourDataServer) {
    $scope.dataLoadedSuccessfully = false;

    yourDataServer
        .query()
        .$promise
        .then(
            function(result) {
                $scope.dataLoaded = true; // set the value to true
            });
}
```

HTML would look like:

```
<div id="loadingBar" ng-show="!dataLoadedSuccessfully">Loading data...</div>

<div id="dataWrapper" ng-show="dataLoadedSuccessfully">
    <!-- data goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: this is good idea, but i'm solve my trouble add $timeout in controller/